# How to delete selected nodes in an html fragment string using PHP?

Tags: php, html

How do you use PHP to take the following html string:

```
$html ="<div><table><tbody><tr>
<td>
<a>Item1</a>
</td>
<td>
<a id="item2">Item2</a>
</td>
<td>
<a>Item3</a>
</td>
</tr></tbody></table></div>";
```

and remove the td node containing an element with `id="item2"`?

The element with the targeted id (item2) can also have other attributes and it's td parent can have other nodes under it.  I want to completely remove the td and everything underneath it if it contains an element with the id= that I'm targeting.

I've spent a good hour trying various things with DOMdocument and similar php functions but am just getting myself confused.

Once the `td` node is removed, I'd like the html string back in the original variable `$html`.

What is the simplest way to do this without generating any errors or warnings?

Comment: You should parse the string to identify remove particular part in php way.

Comment: First replace `<a id="item2">Item2</a>` with `<a id='item2'>Item2</a>`. Whats your question?

Comment: If you can use the javascript then it can be done easily.

Comment: Is using javascript an option? Personally, I think that using javascript would be easier.

Comment: I need to use php for this, and I need to remove the td node as well as any other nodes inside of it (including the a node which has the id I'm looking for).

Comment: My example string is simplified.  There are other nodes and attributes within each td tag.  I want to remove everything inside the td tag as well as the td tag itself that has an element containing the id= that I'm targeting.  Thank you for the help so far!!

Comment: @Blaine I agree with you and could do this very easily in javascript, but that's not an option in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's DOMDocument to parse the string and delete the node. For example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$target_node = $dom->getElementById('item2');
$target_node->parentNode->removeChild($target_node);
$new_html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I've been working on that, but haven't figured out how to do it yet.  I'll keep trying.  Thought there might be a simple answer.

Comment: @user2847853 Just saw you comment and added example to my answer.  The regex approach is really fragile in that if you HTML changes, it may easily break.  You should lean towards using a DOM-based approach when needing to manipulate HTML documents.

Comment: You make a good point and with your example, I've figured it out.  Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex :

```
print_r(preg_replace('#<[^>]+ id="item2">[^<]+</[^>]+>#i', '', $html));
```

the regex is updated now , and you can replcae item2 with $item ,wish it can be very dynamic

retry it i updated it , in php we have to use ## around the regex not the // , sorry

**last updated  :**

```
print_r(preg_replace('#<[^>]+>[^<]*<[^>]+ id="item2"[^>]*>[^<]+</[^>]+>[^<]*</[^>]+>#i', '', $html));
```

Comment: This would be great if it works since it's a one line solution, but I'm getting: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '['. Also if I add other attributes like CLASS= or NAME= to the a tag, I'm not sure if this would handle it.

Comment: use the new code : print_r(preg_replace('#<[^>]+ id="item2">[^<]+</[^>]+>#i', '', $html));  (it's updated )

Comment: Afterwards, the html string still contains an empty td tag.  I guess I could remove that with str_replace though.  However this only works for this specific example.  If I have another attribute like href= after the id= then it doesn't seem to work.  I don't know regex well enough to understand why or how to make it more generic.

Comment: with this one will work even if href="dd" after the id=  ;;; print_r(preg_replace('#<[^>]+ id="item2"[^>]*>[^<]+</[^>]+>#i', '', $html));

Comment: i thought you want to remove only <a id=\"item2\">Item2</a> , not the th tag too ; see the updated answer

Comment: Very good!  Works perfect and no warnings.  A one line solution too.  Thank you very much for helping me get out of the weeds.